# How to determine how Ruby method arguments will be bound without calling the method

Tags: ruby, arguments, parameter-passing

Because there are a few different kinds of method parameters in Ruby (required, default, keyword, variable length...), sometimes determining how actual arguments will be bound to formal parameters can be tricky.

I'm wondering if there's a way to determine what this binding will be *without* actually calling the method. For example, for the following method `A#foo`:

```
class A
   def foo(a, *b, c)
      ...
   end
end
```

I would like a method like `determine_binding` that we can use as follows:

`A.instance_method(:foo).determine_binding(1,2,3,4,5) ## returns { a: 1, b: [2,3,4], c: 5 }`

That is, `determine_binding` takes a list of arguments and determines the formal binding to `foo`'s parameters, without actually having to call `foo`. Is there something like this (or similar) in Ruby?

Comment: I'd probably use one of the `parameters` methods and use the returned array to create a temporary function that you can use to show the actual binding results, but I haven't tried it. Seems like it'd be pretty straight-forward, though.

Comment: Ah, creating a temporary function with the same header is an interesting idea! Assuming there isn't a built-in Ruby solution to my question, I think your approach is the way to go.

Comment: I didn't see one in a very cursory glance, but since there are only a few options for the parameter "types" it may be easy enough to meta up the temp.

Answer (score 3):

You might go with a tiny DSL for that purpose.

```rb
module Watcher
  def self.prepended(base)
    base.instance_methods(false).map do |m|
      mthd = base.instance_method(m)
      names = mthd.parameters.map(&:last).map(&:to_s)
      values = names.join(", ")
      params =
        mthd.parameters.map do |type, name|
          case type
          when :req then name.to_s
          when :rest then "*#{name}"
          when :keyrest then "**#{name}"
          when :block then "&#{name}"
          end
        end.join(", ")
      base.class_eval """
        def #{m}(#{params})
          #{names}.zip([#{values}]).to_h
        end
      """
    end
  end
end

class A; def zoo(a, *b, c); 42; end; end
A.new.zoo(1,2,3,4,5)
#⇒ 42

A.prepend Watcher
A.new.zoo(1,2,3,4,5)
#⇒ {"a"=>1, "b"=>[2, 3, 4], "c"=>5}
```

Answer (score 2):

So close. You're looking for `Method#parameters`

```
A.instance_method(:foo).parameters => [[:req, :a], [:rest, :b], [:req, :c]]
```

See the "[Method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html#method-i-parameters)" documentation for more information.

Comment: This is close to what I want, but it still doesn't give the actual bindings to each parameter. I'm sure I could write any algorithm that determines these bindings but that seems very tedious, and Ruby already does this under-the-hood anyway so I'm wondering if I can avoid re-implementing something that already exists.